# New to Android Help with UI Thread

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to make 4 images to be set invisible and visible after a period of time, something like blue image shows, blue image hides, yellow image shows, yellow image hides. I want to do this with no events, only with a for loop. I am trying the following but it's not working. I am new to android and graphics. Please help me

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {    
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
ImageView[] imViews = new ImageView[4];
ImageView imageView1;
ImageView imageView2;
ImageView imageView3;
ImageView imageView4;

@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.myviewlay);
    imageView1= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    imageView2= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);
    imageView3= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView03);
    imageView4= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView04);


    final ImageView[] imViews = new ImageView[4];
    imViews[0] = imageView1;
    imViews[1] = imageView2;
    imViews[2] = imageView3;
    imViews[3] = imageView4;

    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);                         
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100); 

}

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {  
     public void run() {   

         for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
         {
              imViews[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000); 
              imViews[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000); 
         }

         }};   
}
```

My error log:

```
04-23 05:25:16.383: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 05:25:16.383: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at com.games.game.GameActivity$1.run(GameActivity.java:60)
04-23 05:25:16.383: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-23 05:25:16.383: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-23 05:25:16.383: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-23 05:25:16.383: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
04-23 05:25:16.383: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 05:25:16.383: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-23 05:25:16.383: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-23 05:25:16.383: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-23 05:25:16.383: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: To get rid of the NullPointerException you reported for the different solutions, remove the line `final ImageView[] imViews = new ImageView[4];` from the onCreate() method.

Comment: Wow that workeddddd very niceeely... one last question, i promise >.<, now when it finishes looping it is causing an exception.. how can i terminate the thread safely?

Comment: Never mind guys I got it!! :)... I wish I had your brains :). Thank you so much for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this by using postDelayed() the way you did. The method will not pause your method within the loop. This **can** be achieved by using Thread.sleep(). However, doing this on the UI thread will eventually lead to a forced close because you will block the UI thread for too long.

Basically you need some kind of background thread, doing the waiting for you and which is then posting a runnable to your UI thread showing/hiding the views.

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {  
 public void run() {   

     for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
     {
          final ImageView view = imViews[i];
          mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              }
          });
          try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (Exception e) {} 
          mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }
          });              
          try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (Exception e) {}         
     }

     }};   
}
```

And in the onCreate() method start it with:

```
new Thread(mUpdateTimeTask).start();
```

You might also want to check out the [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) class which can help you with running stuff periodically. There are several ways to do these things.

Comment: Wow thank you stephan, it is telling me the i in imViews[i] needs to be final, when i make i final i can compound i++; how else should i iterate?

Comment: Oh stephan thank you so much for helping me and the patience, I am getting exceptions shown above.. specifically line 65 which is view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
i posted them on my original message

Comment: See my comment to your original post. You need to remove one line from the onCreate() method as you will not fill the member variable with data.

Comment: I am sorry I am such a newb, so what should i change to avoid such exception...? imViews is a static array so that i can use it in the mUpdateTask..., which is the variable causing the problem?, I am sorry all this view, images.. runnables are new to me :( –

Comment: Wow that workeddddd very niceeely... one last question, i promise >.<, now when it finishes looping it is causing an exception.. how can i terminate the thread safely?

Comment: Never mind guys I got it!! :)... I wish I had your brains :). Thank you so much for all your help

Comment: Stephan, Do you think you could help me with one last thing, if its not too much?... I am almost done.. but i will need to repost my code.. only if you can help me :) if not its ok I understand you guys have done a lot for me

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
imViews[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Also as @MByD says, improve your code by calling this only once.

Comment: Oh thank you I did not realize, but right now it is giving me an exception, is there somthing I am doing wrong? i am sorry I am new to Android and the Graphic things... the log cat says there is an error at line 60 and line 60 is mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

Comment: What's the exception? Is it the first or the second postDelayed?

Comment: on the second, but then i commented it out and now it says imViews[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); is a NullPointException

Comment: Try something like this in your run() :
`
if(imViews[i] != null){
  imViews[i].setVisibility( imViews[i].getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
  mHandler.postDelayed( ... );
}else{
  // Log something
}
`

Comment: The imViews member variable is never filled, as there is a local variable with the same name defined in the onCreate() method.

Comment: I am sorry I am such a newb, so what should i change to avoid such exception...? imViews is a static array so that i can use it in the mUpdateTask..., which is the variable causing the problem?, I am sorry all this view, images.. runnables are new to me :(

Comment: It's not about Runnable at all. You're declaring your variable as an instance variable and then as a local variable in the onCreate method. You should declare it only once, otherwise it'll keep giving you NPE (cos the instance variable is never initialized, just replaced with the onCreate one).

Comment: Never mind guys I got it!! :)... I wish I had your brains :). Thank you so much for all your help